# How to retrieve xsl:output media-type value from xsl file via ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

Is there a way to retrieve the media-type value? e.g. like OutputSettings.OutputMethod used to get xsl:output method.

Answer (score 2):

```
XPathNavigator objArgXPathNavigator = objArgXsltDocument.CreateNavigator();
XPathExpression objXPathExpression = objArgXPathNavigator.Compile("/*/xsl:output/@media-type");
XmlNamespaceManager objXmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(objArgXPathNavigator.NameTable);
objXmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
objXPathExpression.SetContext(objXmlNamespaceManager);

XPathNodeIterator nodes = objArgXPathNavigator.Select(objXPathExpression);
while (nodes.MoveNext())
{
  objArgHttpContext.Response.Write(nodes.Current.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could query the XSL stylesheet via your preferred method of handling XML (for example as an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28VS.80%29.aspx)) and issue the following XPath query (don't forget to make the xsl namespace available to XPath beforehand with a `NamespaceManager`):

```
/*/xsl:output/@media-type
```

The equivalent could be also achieved with LINQ.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak. It works. I never thought XSLT is similar structure as XML. Cool.

Comment: @HH: XSLT ist not a "similar structure", XSLT *is* XML - simple as that. ;)